# Getting readily usable output in R?

Tags: r, output

I have split my df into a list containing 500 groups thus:

```
c1=cut(SNP_Allele_Frequency$College_SE,500)
splitc1=split(SNP_Allele_Frequency,c1,drop=FALSE)
```

Then I have got the mean for all components of the list so:

```
sink("acb1.txt")
lapply(splitc1, function(x) mean(x$ACB))
sink()
```

Problem is, I need to save the output into Excel-readable or R usable format, but the output has all the information and I have to copy each case manually to use it.What I mean is that I need only the mean value (e.g. 0.3879208) and not the rest of the output(e.g. $`(-0.001,0.01]`
[1]) and I wanna save it as a column/vector so that I can directly use it.

```
$`(-0.001,0.01]`
[1] 0.3879208

$`(0.01,0.02]`
[1] 0.3855017

$`(0.02,0.03]`
[1] 0.379335

$`(0.03,0.04]`
[1] 0.3769094
```

Comment: `as.character(unlist(lapply(splitc1, function(x) mean(x$ACB))))` ; unlist makes it a single vector and as.character removes the names

Comment: This is better but each row contains 6 cases, instead of 1, so I end up with 16 rows instead of 100(100 is the number of components): "0.387920777218443" "0.385501709167821" "0.379334987419263" "0.376909435983493" "0.383703895370679" "0.375541410387485"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it so:`ibs1=as.character(unlist(lapply(splitc1, function(x) mean(x$IBS))))
write.table(ibs1,file="ibs1.csv",row.names=FALSE)`